# How do I cite users who suggest content in comments

Tags: support, answers, comments

Sometimes, I see answers to questions that have comments that kinda "continue" the explanation out of the answer. Such comments add valuable information that would be better off within the answer. I feel like adding all the information in the comments into the answer to make it complete, but I also want to acknowledge the comment writer. How would I go about doing this?

**Note:** This thought sprung after seeing Ben Norris' comment in [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81624/friedel-crafts-alkylation-of-benzene-using-tetrachloromethane-with-aluminium-ch/81628#comment144307_81628)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mention the user name of the user who wrote the comment.**

Comments are not meant for eternity and everybody who writes a comment here must know that it is subject to deletion once it has served its cause. If you integrate a comment into a post, the comment should be flagged as *no longer needed*. Therefore, there is little point in attempting to link the comment directly since it will disappear.

Thus, the name and the fact that it was a comment is all the durable information you have. Present this.

Please don’t, however, mention the user with an @ preceeding their name. In comments, this @ serves a pinging purpose, but it is not possible to ping users from the body of a post. There is also no need to highlight that this is a username since anybody with a decent understanding of English should be able to realise that we are dealing with a name in this context. An added @ disrupts the flow of text, however. It is therefore typographically desirable to leave it out.

Comment: Those @ are really distracting me to the point I don't understand this answer anymore.

Comment: @hBy2Py I like your edit =)